# How to execute appium scripts in browserstack using AppiumDriver?

Tags: selenium, appium, browserstack

I want to automate my web application in mobile native browsers.In my local simulators i can do it using appium.But if i want to run in Browserstack i am not able to initialize appium driver.I have to initialize WebDriver to run scripts in mobile browsers.How can i run script sin browserstack mobile devices using Appium Driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize your tests using Appium driver on BrowserStack Automate using below code snippet:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("os_version", "10.3");
    caps.setCapability("device", "iPhone 7");
    caps.setCapability("real_mobile", "true");
    AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://<userName>:<AutomateKey>@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub"), caps);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```